# Why aren't there any SDKs to call Cloud SQL API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'd like to call Cloud SQL API described below from Cloud Functions.

- https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export?hl=en

And I found libraries to call GCP APIs.

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go

However, there does not seem to be any modules for Cloud SQL.

I'm wondering why it's not implemented. is the reason that the APIs are relatively new? or that I misunderstand the purpose of the libraries and actually it shouldn't be implemented in the libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the page that you [linked](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export?hl=en#examples) you will find a sample code in different languages to call that API by building a client. For example a sample code for `Node.js` would look like this:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
var sqlAdmin = google.sqladmin('v1beta4');

authorize(function(authClient) {
  var request = {
    // Project ID of the project that contains the instance to be exported.
    project: 'my-project',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // Cloud SQL instance ID. This does not include the project ID.
    instance: 'my-instance',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    resource: {
      // TODO: Add desired properties to the request body.
    },

    auth: authClient,
  };

  sqlAdmin.instances.export(request, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  });
});

function authorize(callback) {
  google.auth.getApplicationDefault(function(err, authClient) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('authentication failed: ', err);
      return;
    }
    if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
      var scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'];
      authClient = authClient.createScoped(scopes);
    }
    callback(authClient);
  });
}
```

To connect to a Cloud SQL instance from Cloud Function follow the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql).

Comment: thanks, I totally missed it and now I found that not google-cloud-node but google-api-nodejs-client has the interface to call the APIs. I don't understand the difference completely but anyway now I can try. thanks again.

Comment: For anyone looking: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sqladmin/classes/Resource$Instances-1.html If you scroll down the page, you see an example of the import in much cleaner code (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gcloud sdk to call the the apis. If you simply wish to export database please have a look at this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/export

Comment: thanks for your answer. from my understanding, the library google-cloud-node / google-cloud-go have the same functions as the sdk. I'm wondering why there are some functions which the libraries does not have but the sdk has. And as I'd like to call the APIs inside Cloud Functions, it's desirable to use it directly from JS or Go etc.